# Reading csv file with no column names python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I wanted to ask that i got a data of 80 columns and all of them have no names and its 80 columns and 12500 rows long and  there are blank columns between them

```
8,1,,0,1993,146,,2,1,,,,,,,,,,2.1,0.65,0.15,0.65,19.1,,18.03,,,19.6,,,0.06,,,,,,19.1,19.6294717,19.36473585,0.06,,,,51.25,19.3,23.3,-0.04,-0.04,0.34,0.07,0.16,,,0.16,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,15.3,7.8,11.55,58,100,79,15.4,8,11.7
```

I want to use this csv file and i want to delete the extra blank columns which i might do from using the code line

```
data = data.dropna()
```

bur it only can delete the rows i think further  more how can I access or name the particular column
`data = pd.read_csv('CollectedData.csv')`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use this [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with `header=None` and [`pandas.DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) on `axis=1`:

```
data = pd.read_csv("CollectedData.csv", header=None).dropna(axis=1, how="all")
```

If you need to give names to each column, use `names` parameter:

```
cols_names= ["ColA", "ColB", "ColC", ..]

data = (
        pd.read_csv("CollectedData.csv",
                    header=None,
                    names=cols_names)
            .dropna(axis=1, how="all")
        )
```

Comment: But there is no effect of anything at all I mean pd.read_csv("CollectedData.csv") and pd.read_csv("CollectedData.csv", header=None).dropna(axis=1, how="all") just red the same columns and stuff so the unnamed header and the data is erased but how can i delete the blank columns

Comment: No, the code I shared is based on your example. On my machine, with yours I get 80 columns while with mine I get 37 columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'm able to rename the columns as well as I deleted the rest of the columns by just      `data  = data[['Age','AMV','Met','Dwpt','plane Rad-temp','AirTemp','MeanRad-temp','Velocity','ATurb','VaporPressure','Humidity','PMV','TaOutdoor','RhOutdoor']]`